# How to correctly set the list property? (Error 381)

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a listbox which can be filtered according to keyword in textbox. It works if I do it normally. However, it stopped working when the list is a dependent source. (The listbox value is like `INDIRECT()` of F1 and I'm trying to filter that INDIRECT list)

I have 3 lists as shown in the image (A, B, D). D is a list of A without duplicates. the `listbox("lbxCustomers")` in Userform2 uses a dependent rowsource according to word selected at Cell F2. [It works until here]

The values in the listbox will be filtered according to keyword in `textbox("tbxFind")`. I'm getting an error at this line "`.List = vaCustNames`". I tried to change it into a normal range (`sheet1.range(...)`) and it works but the list is not a dependent list of F1.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz9qK.jpg)

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Me.lbxCustomers.RowSource = Range("F2").Value

End Sub


Private Sub tbxFind_Change()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim sCrit As String
    Dim vaCustNames As Variant

    vaCustNames = Range("F2").Value
    Debug.Print Range("F2").Value

    sCrit = "*" & UCase(Me.tbxFind.Text) & "*"

    With Me.lbxCustomers
        .RowSource = ""
        'Start with a fresh list
        .List = vaCustNames
        '.List = Sheet1.Range("B2:B13").Value 'tested with range and worked
       For i = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            'Remove the line if it doesn’t match
           If Not UCase(.List(i)) Like sCrit Then
                .RemoveItem i
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `.List` expects an array. You are feeding a variant, possibly of string type. Of course, the ListBox requires a string value, but if it is a single string you should use the `Add` method to add it to the list, and if you wish to assign to the `List` property, you must be sure that it is an array, even one with a single value only.

Comment: @Variatus I guess the question becomes, how do I store the values in listbox into an arrary? From your suggestion, I should be able to set it as a  list property from this new array. (The values in the listbox is dependent of cell F1).

Comment: You can use `vaCustNames = .List` to store the items in the array.

Comment: How F1 gets its value shouldn't make any difference. What sort of value is it? Is it a string? Or perhaps a string representing a range address, or a named range?